# python manage.py runserver just answer first request

Tags: python, django, vue.js, server

First time using Django and Vue in a project. Lots of problems managing to use them both together. Now, when everything seems to be working, when I start running command: "python manage.py runserver" it seems to begin, but after first (sometimes after second or third) request it stops listening, but no error is displayed. So annoying start over and over again when I change something, since I am trying to make requests and I have to try a lot.

I appreciate any light on my darkness right now.

Comment: Are you sure this is not an SSL/firewall/other security issue?

Comment: What happens when you make a request after the server has "stopped"?

Comment: The request stays pending and it never answer it. Also for security issue, I dont know because in that case I should not answer any request but it does (for seconds)